# error when I try to load a fixture

Tags: symfony

When I try to run the load method in the console I get this error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>
> Could not find any fixture services to load.

I created under my AppBundle folders DataFixtures\ORM so why I get this error ?

Also when I have more than one bundle how I can tell Symfony which fixture to load ?

```
namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;


use AppBundle\Entity\Movie;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class LoadMovieData implements FixtureInterface
{

    /**
     * Load data fixtures with the passed EntityManager
     *
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $movie = new Movie();
        $movie->setTitle('Green Mile');
        $movie->setDescription('fdgs sdfg sdg');
        $movie->setTime(23);
        $movie->setYear(2341);

        $manager->persist($movie);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: --fixtures[=FIXTURES]    The directory to load data fixtures from. (multiple values allowed)
That's how you choose which fixtures to load.

Comment: @SergeiKutanov Thanks but I followed a tutorial where the instructor just run the command `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load` without specify directory is it because I have more than one Bundle ?

Comment: should not be a problem, that's how I run mine. And the command you use should run all fixtures

Comment: so why I get error "Could not find any fixture services to load." ? I am on windows 10 btw

Comment: stupid question, but do you have <?php in the first line of your fixtures file?

Comment: no problem yes I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160309/discussion-between-sergei-kutanov-and-wel).

Comment: I will post my appkernel too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an update to the fixtures bundle since 3.0
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

You don't implement FixturesInterface but extend Fixutres class -

```
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
class LoadMovieData extends Fixture {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to append `Fixture` to both your file and class :

`AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadMovieDataFixture.php`

`class LoadMovieDataFixture`